# less doesn't page the output when called inside env

Tags: terminal, environment-variables, less, pager

After an update I noticed that my bash profile for `man` colorization breaks paging. I don't know what changed but I narrowed it down to the fact that calling `env less hello.txt` results in contents of `hello.txt` being echoed to the terminal (like `cat`) without the paging behavior. How do I debug and fix this?

To eliminate the effect of some environment variables, I tested with the minimal environment:

```
env -i TERM=xterm-256color /usr/bin/less hello.txt
```

or even:

```
env -i /usr/bin/less hello.txt
```

This also simply prints the file to stdout. On a different machine with the same software versions, the paging works (if `TERM` is preserved).

Since even `env -i` behaves differently, I don't suppose that the reason is something in my environment.

Versions of `less` and `env` are the same: `less 581.2 (PCRE2 regular expressions)` and `GNU coreutils 8.32`, OS is Arch Linux 64 bit, up to date, shell: `GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: Is `less` an alias or function? What does `type less; type env` output?

Comment: Goddammit... I typed out the full path to `less` to be sure, but I didn't think of `env`. If I do `/usr/bin/env` instead, it works. The alias comes from the same `grc` package: `env is aliased to 'colourify env'`.

Comment: Wow, I would file a bug against this package. `env` is a simple tool with a simple job and messing with it is bound to create this kind of weird problem.

Comment: colourify is in turn aliased to `grc -es`, where `-es` means that it redirects the stdout and stderr of invoked commands. Not sure how the redirection is used, but I guess `less` detects it and changes behavior accordingly.

Comment: `less` behaves like `cat` when its output is not a terminal, so that you can have a program (such as `man`) automatically pipe to `less`, but still pipe its output if you want.

Comment: It's funny: I confirmed that `grc` didn't break `env` before the last version, although it intended to. The alias assignments were all there, but in a file `/etc/profile.d/grc.bashrc`. It was [renamed](https://github.com/garabik/grc/commit/f2ace181917334db111c2776cee07a225d809281) to `/etc/profile.d/grc.sh` in the last release, which finally caused it to be sourced on my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely explanation for `env foo …` behaving differently from a plain `foo …` is that `foo` is a function or alias. Since `env` is an external command, it looks up `foo` as an external command.

Here, though, `env` itself turned out to be an alias. Obviously, if `env` isn't the standard `env` command, it might behave differently.

this turned out to be a bug in [grc](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/%7Egarabik/software/grc.html) which sets up a file [included during the bash startup](https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/grc.sh) (there are zsh and fish versions as well) which defines many commands, including `env`, as aliases: `env` is aliased to `grc -es env`. `grc -es …` runs the specified command with its standard output and standard error both redirected to a pipe in which `grc` inserts escape sequences to change the text color. This is fine for commands that produce output that humans want to read in a nicely formatted way. But it doesn't make sense to do it for `env`, which is a command whose primary role is to invoke another command with a modified environment. Automatically redirecting the output and error output of `foo` to a pipe when the user runs `env foo` is disruptive, and it's useless anyway since grc doesn't know how to colorize the output. I guess the goal was to colorize the output of `env` with no arguments, which displays the environment, but this is pretty useless since the output of `env` is not very user-friendly in the first place: `export` does a better job, as unlike `env` it produces sorted output (and quoted in a form that makes values with newlines unambiguous).

Comment: Thank you for the catch, now I can sleep more peacefully. I filed an issue with `grc`: https://github.com/garabik/grc/issues/181